# Issue in starting Apache from direct url Localhost

Tags: php, apache, web, server, xampp

[image]

I used to work on localhost before and never had such issue, the issue was with Apache that was not starting so I went to my http.conf file and changed the port 80 to 8080 and from then I have to put the url present in the image. I just want to use the "localhost/projectname" which is not running at the moment.

Comment: `localhost/projectname` is nothing else but `localhost:80/projectname` change your port to 80. Maybe some other application is running on port 80 at the moment ... stop it before you start apache

Comment: Xampp is not running on port 80, so i changed to 8080 then it worked but all  i want is to run simply like "localhost/projectname" not localhost:8080/.

Comment: If you do not want to add a port and use `localhost/projectname` than this means you have to use port 80, period! Check what app an your system is using port 80. mayby some anti virus software